# Optaplanner check solver manager status

Tags: optaplanner

I am building a system that will consist of several instances, each running our Optaplanner implementation. These instances will monitor a common queue for incoming jobs. I don't want an instance that is already busy to take the job, so I want to check the number of ongoing jobs in the solver manager.

In the debugger, it looks like the solverManager has some stuff that could help me check that (`problemIdToSolverJobMap.size() < parallelSolverCount` would work for instance), but these are private ant not accesible to me.

How do I in the most robust way check the status of the solver manager as a whole, not for a specific job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be useful indeed. This is an API gap, clearly. [Please create a jira.](https://issues.redhat.com)